# Rails controller action without a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I just want to do a rails action without a view.

In my **'routes.rb'**

```
resources :pictures do
    member do 
        post 'dislike'  
    end  
end
```

In my **'PictureController.rb'**
this does not work

```
def dislike
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    @like = Like.find(:user_id => current_user.id, :picture_id => params[:id])

    @like.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :action => :show, :id => params[:id], notice: 'You don\'t  like this picture anymore.' }
        format.json { render json: @picture }
    end
end
```

neither do this

```
def dislike
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    @like = Like.find(:user_id => current_user.id, :picture_id => params[:id])

    @like.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @picture, notice: 'You don\'t  like this picture anymore.' }
        format.json { render json: @picture }
    end
end
```

or even this (but this is not the case for me, i want a feedback to the user via json and via html)

```
def dislike
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    @like = Like.find(:user_id => current_user.id, :picture_id => params[:id])

    @like.destroy

    render :nothing => true
end
```

But i keep getting this error message:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template pictures/dislike, application/like with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.
```

How should i tell rails that this action in PicturesController does not needs a view?

## Solved!

I didn't really solved the problem of telling rails i did not need a view, i just created another controller, put the method in it, and told rails routing to match the dislike action with a `match` call.
I cannot tell for sure, but i think it was a problem with the `resources :picture` in my `routes.rb` file...

But anyway, thank you guys!
=)

Comment: call `render :nothing => true`

Comment: I assume that you don't actually want to render :nothing though, right? You're trying to render the json, or the show page?

Comment: Yes, i want to render something, although `render :nothing => true` did not work either =(

Comment: Why is it asking for the `pictures/like` template in the `dislike` action? I'm beginning to think we're getting a pretty confused picture of exactly under what circumstances the error occurs.

Comment: Just edited the question, i had pasted the wrong error =x

Comment: what's the `show` action look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just created another controller with the dislike action:

```
def dislike
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    @like = Like.find(:user_id => current_user.id, :picture_id => params[:id])

    @like.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'You don\'t  like this picture anymore.' }
        format.json { render json: @picture }
    end
end
```

and modified my routes.rb to match this action:

```
match 'pictures/:id/dislike' => "likes#dislike", :via => :post
```

and my link to dislike now is

```
<%= link_to 'Dislike!', {:action => :dislike, :controller => :likes}, :method => :post %>
```

Answer (score 26):

Something like this?

```
def dislike
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id]
    @like = Like.find(:user_id => current_user.id, :picture_id => params[:id])

    @like.destroy

    render :nothing => true
end
```

Comment: `:nothing` will be deprecated in rails 5.1 in favour of `head`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the problem is that you're hitting this action via an ajax request. So the controller is looking for `format.js`, but you haven't specified a response for that format in your block. Thus it's falling through to the default.

Try

```
format.js { render json: @picture }
```

You may also need to tell the ajax request to expect a json response.

Comment: Actually it fails in both HTML via browser and the test cases

Comment: I assume you mean that you're entering the path in the browser bar to test the html render? In that case, you ought to get a routing error - you've defined a `post` route, not a `get`.

Comment: No, i've put a link to the action with `<%= link_to 'Like!', {:action => :like}, :method => :post %>`, and the error i get is the error described in the question...

Comment: @CrystianLeão I think that generates `pictures/like` rather than `pictures/1/like`, correct? (1 can be any ID)

Comment: @varatis No, the link is correct, it points to `/pictures/980190963/like` (when the link is at pictures/980190963)